# ¿Podría enviarse una notificación en las preguntas seguidas si se marca una respuesta como aceptada?

Tags: característica-nueva, respuesta-aceptada, seguir-publicación

Cuando uno sigue una publicacion se le notifica si se añadio algun comentario, una respuesta, o si se elimino la publicacion o se realizo alguna edicion, pero no se notifica si se marco una respuesta como aceptada.

Mi propuesta es que se valore enviar una notificación si en la publicación se marcó una respuesta como aceptada (no se si tambien seria bueno que se notificara si hubo votos en la publicacion).

Comment: recomiendo usar las etiquetas más a conciencia y poner títulos más descriptivos :P

Comment: Y esto.. es para meta general.. no para aca...

Comment: @gbianchi, me gusta ver primero como se recibe por la comunidad antes de subirlo a meta